# How to restrict gitlab variables in a group to be accessible from other allowed repos

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a use-case where i want to have restricted access to certain repos i have under gitlab group `groupA` and i have couple of repos under this group like `repo1`, and `repo2`. I want to setup certain highly confidential variables as secrets under this group `groupA` so that all repos under it can access those variables

Since there repos host several gitlab CI shared templates that other non-restrictive repos call and use, i want these variables to be pulled from the shared templates maintained in the restricted group. Is this something currently possible with gitlab CI?

So `example1` repo can use shared template from `repo1` that then uses these variables under group `groupA`, but members of repo `example1` still cant's have access to these variables. Only way is via pipeline from the shared templates. `repo1` is able to access variables since it is under group `groupA` where the variables are setup

This is a great use-case am sure many people will want also, so not sure if am one of few raising this

Answer (score 1):

No, what you're describing is not possible with GitLab's security model. CI configurations do not themselves carry secrets. Projects and groups do. You cannot obtain secrets just by including a CI configuration.

> members of repo `example1` still cant's have access to these variables. Only way is via pipeline from the shared templates

One way you could do something like this would be to put the variable in a common ancestor group. Members of descendent subgroups should not be members of this common ancestor group. The result is that pipelines for projects in subgroups will inherit the variables, but users will not be able to reveal the variables in the GitLab UI or API.

For example, the root of the hierarchy is a group called `common`. `GroupA` is a subgroup of `common` `example1` would be a descendent of `common` but not a descendent of `GroupA`. `example1` pipelines could use variables defined in the `common` group, but members would not be able to see/change the values. Variables set directly in `GroupA` would remain confidential to members of `GroupA`.

For self-managed GitLab instances, Aanother alternative to this would be using [Instance level CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-an-instance), where only an instance administrator can see/change the values of the variable.

Another *possible* way to do this would be to have group-specific or project-specific CI/CD runners where variables are set on the runner, if you use self-hosted runners. However, this *could* lead to an inefficient allocation of runner resources, depending on how you configure this.

### Vault

If you use HasiCorp Vault, that opens other possibilities with the [vault integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) which can control access to secrets based on JWT claims, which can include the project requesting the secret. Many organizations manage their production secrets using Vault -- so it can be ideal to provision/manage access to secrets in the same way in GitLab as the rest of the organization.

For example, you may setup a [Vault bound claim](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/jwt#bound-claims) like this for secrets you want `GroupA` to access:

```json
"namespace_path": "GroupA"
```

Of course, this requires both (1) that you use Vault for storing your secrets and (2) a Premium subscription entitlement.

Comment: yeah am aware of that..was just hoping there is some workaround somewhere and if not, when will we get something like this with gitlab you know

Comment: For advanced use-cases, you would probably consider using Vault @uberrebu -- I added that to my answer.

Comment: i know about vault..and the complexity of setup and management makes it a horrible product...can work for certain team but it isn't a great product for many scenarios